# Bootstrap nesting going bad

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I`m having problems with Bootstrap grid nesting in a project. I've created a div with a grid of 12 and a class with a background image.

After that, I created 3 other grids, one of 3 other with 8 and the last one with 1, for a total of 12. However, when I duplicate it, it doesn`t go to the next line as supposed to..

The link to see it is: https://www.neevasoft.com/test/saude.html

The code is here:

```
 <article id="blog-list" class="blog-list article3 gradient-7">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <h2 class="title text-center">Saúde</h2>
          <div class="item col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
              <div class="item1 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                  <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                      <a href="interno.html">
                          <img class="img-responsive2" src="assets/images/blog/blog-1.jpg" alt="">
                      </a>
                  </figure>
              </div>
              <div class="item2 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                  <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                      <a href="interno.html">
                          Espaço Corporal Eloiza Bovió
                      </a>
                  </figure>
              </div>
              <div class="item3 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                  <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                      <a href="interno.html">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </a>
                  </figure>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                  <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                      <a href="interno.html">
                          <img class="img-responsive2" src="assets/images/blog/blog-1.jpg" alt="">
                      </a>
                  </figure>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                  <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                      <a href="interno.html">
                          Espaço Corporal Eloiza Bovió
                      </a>
                  </figure>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                  <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                      <a href="interno.html">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </a>
                  </figure>
              </div>
            </div><!--//row-->
        </div><!--//container-->
    </article>
```

Comment: looks like you are missing a closing `</div>` tag for you `.item`

Comment: Yes, that`s true, I fixed, updated, but still the same.

Comment: if you want to duplicate columns set, you need to do it including `<div class="row">`

Comment: 1) When using a grid, *all* content should be inside columns. 2) When nesting columns (at least with Bootstrap's grid), include rows between.

Comment: Try to remove z-index: 10 from .navmenu

Answer (score 0):

You should not be nesting col-* divs

Try using this:

```
<article id="blog-list" class="blog-list article3 gradient-7">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="title text-center">Saúde</h2>
        <div class="item1 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="item2 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html">
                    Espaço Corporal Eloiza Bovió
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="item3 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>

    </div><!--//row-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html">
                    Espaço Corporal Eloiza Bovió
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--//container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to fix it

```
<article id="blog-list" class="blog-list article3 gradient-7">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 class="title text-center">Saúde</h2>
      <div class="item col-xs-12"> 
       <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="item1 col-xs-3">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html"><img class="img-responsive2" src="assets/images/blog/blog-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="item2 col-xs-8">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html">Espaço Corporal Eloiza Bovió</a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="item3 col-xs-1">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="item1 col-xs-3">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html"><img class="img-responsive2" src="assets/images/blog/blog-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="item2 col-xs-8">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html">Espaço Corporal Eloiza Bovió</a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="item3 col-xs-1">
            <figure class="figure-wrapper">
                <a href="interno.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--//row-->
</div><!--//container-->
```